# PHP EMPTY token

Tags: php, constants

```
define('EMPTY', '');
if(!empty(EMPTY))
{
if(!(boolean) _CONSTANT)
{
    print "One";
}
}
```

The above code produces the following error message:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'EMPTY' (T_EMPTY) in C:\Users\Robert\Documents\web development\xampp\htdocs\xampp\web_development\index.php on line 3"

Nowhere in the PHP Manual does it explicitly state that "EMPTY" is a token nor does it inform you about this pitfall.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Function names are case insensitive.

```
$state = constant('EMPTY');
if (!empty($state)) {
```

Comment: This will only work in PHP 5.5 which is still in alpha stage as `empty()` cannot accept expressions otherwise.

Comment: `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context`

Comment: OOOOOOhhhh I missed that little word, "variable" from the manual with regards to the empty documentation. Now it all makes sense. Thanks very much!

Comment: This answer is incorrect - it has nothing to do with case sensitivity. Constants can have the same name as previously declared functions. But they cannot have the same name as language keywords.

Comment: @robertrocha leepower's answer is the correct reason as to why your code does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare constants with the same name as functions as PHP uses `()` to determine if a token is a function or constant declaration:

```
<?php
function myfunc() {
 echo "inside myfunc()\n";
}
define('str_replace', 'my string');
echo str_replace . "\n";
echo str_replace("A", "B", "AAAA") . "\n";
define('myfunc', 'this is myfunc constant');
echo myfunc . "\n";
myfunc();

/*
Output:
my string
BBBB
this is myfunc constant
inside myfunc()
 */
```

This doesn't work for `empty` because `empty` is a [language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem... just pick another name for your constant.

If you would like, you can [submit a documentation bug report](https://bugs.php.net/report.php).

Comment: I can't agree that undocumented keywords aren't a problem.

Comment: @kojiro, Let me rephrase... it isn't a problem for you once you know about it.  Just pick a new name.  If you have a problem with it, file a bug report using the link I posted.  Of course it's a problem in general.